# Registering routes with ASP.Net 5's MVC 6 Attribute Routing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, attributerouting

When using Attribute Routing in ASP.Net MVC 5 you would call the command `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` and then just add the `Route()` tag to the Controller/Actions you wanted to build routes to. I am now trying to do this in ASP.Net MVC 6 and have found many pages that show you how to do it, which is really no different than in MVC 5, but they don't show you where or how to register those routes.

Does ASP.Net MVC 6 just due it for you automatically or is there an equivalent to `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` that I have to call some where?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have enabled MVC in your Startup class using `app.UseMvc()`, then you already have support for routing via the `RouteAttribute`.

You can just add the `RouteAttribute` to a method of one of your controllers, e.g.:

```
[Route("/example")]
public IActionResult Example()
{
    // …
}
```

That makes the route available under `/example` instead of the default `/ControllerName/Example`.

You can also use the `RouteAttribute` on the controller class, e.g.

```
[Route("test/[action]")]
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    // …
}
```

So actions would be available under `/test/MethodName` instead of `Example/MethodName`.