# Listing API Methods Under Multiple Groups

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have Swashbuckle annotated code that looks like this:

```
[Route("api/Subscribers/{id}/[controller]")]
[Route("api/Organizations/{id}/[controller]")]
public class AddressesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{aid}")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(PostalRecord))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAddress(Guid id, Guid aid)
    {
       //do something
    }
```

I would like to use the [`GroupActionsBy` customization, as shown in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175018/grouping-of-api-methods-in-documentation-is-there-some-custom-attribute), but I want to have the above `GetAddress` method simultaneously included into two separate groups that correspond to the two route prefixes shown:

```
[Route("api/Subscribers/{id}/[controller]")]
[Route("api/Organizations/{id}/[controller]")]
```

In other words, I want the same method to be listed under both:

- Subscribers
- Organizations

**How can this be done?**

Incidentally, I'm working with ASP.NET Core (`dnx46`).  If it is not yet possible to do this with the ASP.NET Core version of Swashbucklee, then a full-CLR (Web API 2.2?) example would still be appreciated.

Also, for a more complete story of what I'm trying to do - I have a [separate SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522617/route-disambiguation-in-asp-net-core-mvc-6).

### Update

The answer given by @venerik got me close to the solution.  When I apply his sample code...

```
[SwaggerOperation(Tags = new []{"Subscribers", "Organizations"})]
```

...this causes the Swagger listings to look like this:

[image]

In short, the "Addresses" endpoints are now appearing under the headings that I want but, as the red arrow indicates, they are now also being "cross-listed"; I don't want the "Subscribers" endpoint being listed under the "Organizations" endpoint.

I'm suspicious that a [SwaggerOperationFilter] might be "the other half" of the answer, if I can make it remove the cross-listed entries.  I've not played with that mechanism before.

### Angst

Also, it is very unfortunate that [SwaggerOperation] can only be applied on methods/actions.  I would rather apply it to the class itself:

```
[Route("api/Subscribers/{id}/[controller]")]
[Route("api/Organizations/{id}/[controller]")]
[SwaggerOperation(Tags = new []{"Subscribers", "Organizations"})]
public class AddressesController : Controller
{
```

Is there any remedy for this?

Comment: for .net 5 adding `c.EnableAnnotations();` within `.AddSwaggerGen(c =>` in the startup is also required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@venerik got me on the right path.  But instead of a `[SwaggerOperation]` attribute, what I needed was a `[SwaggerOperationFilter]`, like this:

```
public class CategorizeFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        string path = context.ApiDescription.RelativePath;
        string segment = path.Split('/')[1];

        if (segment != context.ApiDescription.GroupName)
        {
            operation.Tags = new List<string> { segment };
        }
    }
}
```

Then I just decorate my actions as needed:

```
[Route("api/Subscribers/{id}/[controller]")]
[Route("api/Organizations/{id}/[controller]")]
public class AddressesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{aid}")]
    [SwaggerOperationFilter(typeof(CategorizeFilter))]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(PostalRecord))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAddress(Guid id, Guid aid)
    {
       //do something
    }
```

As a consequence, the "Addresses" category completely disappeared from my Swagger UI (good!) and the twin set of endpoint routes are properly divided between "Organizations" and "Subscribers" groups.  Perfect!

Comment: yes it will work but one major drawback is, whenever you will create a new contract you must add one new block in the category filter class in swagger. so in other words you must make changes in 2 different project. instead of that i would like to use [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new []{"Subscribers", "Organizations"})] attribute.

Answer (score 8):

I do not have experience with ASP.NET Core (yet) but in ASP.NET Web API you can achieve this with the `SwaggerOperationAttribute`. You can use this attribute to add tags to operations. For instance, the next piece of code adds the tags `Subscribers` and `Organizations`:

```
[SwaggerOperation(Tags = new []{"Subscribers", "Organizations"})]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAddress(Guid id, Guid aid)
{
   //do something
}
```

Swagger-UI groups operations by tag, so, `GetAddress` will get listed under both `Subscribers` and `Organizations`.

Comment: I've updated my question, based on your very helpful input.

Comment: superb!! would it be possible to get Subscribers and Organizations from any json or text file?